# Can you add a fifth number to a rummikub set of four?

Tags: rummikub

For instance, if there are four  8s on the table, can I add another 8 to it?

Comment: In general these sorts of questions can be answered by simply reading the rules. If you've read the rules, and find they're not clear, then edit your question with the relevant excerpts from the rules and explain why they're not clear.

Answer (score 2):

In a standard rummikub set, there are 4 colors. All tiles in a set must be different so you can only have 4 tiles with same number and different color.

[A group is formed when three or four tiles of the same numbers are put together; like suits in a deck of cards, each number will have a different color.](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/leisure/brain-games/rummikub1.htm)

However, if you have 2 tiles to add, you can take one and create a second set of three.